# Are Chinese and Japanese characters decomposed the same way?

Tags: characters

Decomposition Option of the Chinese Character 天 tiān ‘sky’

天 tiān ‘sky’
一 yī one
大 dà big
一 yī one
人 rén man

天一 大 一 人

NB. Synonyms: Structural analysis of the Chinese characters, Breakdown of the Chinese characters, Chinese characters split.

Comment: Japanese kanji came from Chinese characters. Some kanji retain the original meaning, some do not.  Beside some Japanese original coined new kanji, they are exactly the same characters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Japanese characters are Chinese in their nature, aren't they?

Answer (score 3):

Almost all Japanese characters (in my experience >99%) are exist in Chinese. Few are changed a little, like 宮 and 宫. As a Chinese, I have no difficulty in recognizing Japanese characters.

Some of Chinese characters is simplified in simplified Chinese, but remain unchanged in Japanese, like 車 and 车.

There are some rare Japanese characters which doesn't has corresponding Chinese character.　But they are still formed by components used in other characters.

Comment: How often and when Chinese character decomposition is applied to Japanese characters?

Comment: Almost always except hiragana and katakana.